# NFS on ProxMox linked clones

Tags: nfs, proxmox, ubuntu-23.10

PREAMBLE:
I'm trying to create a single master VM on my ProxMox server with several linked clones VM using NFS to share te assigned disk drive.
My reasoning is that if I assign the master with 3Tb of disk and then share that with all the linked clones it will enable better usage of the disk when compared with setting an arbitrary disk size for each VM.
Also I believed that by having all the installed applications done on the Master system I'd only need to update/upgrade the master and then reboot all VMs fo the upgraded applications to be accessible on each linked VM.
Originally I was planning on simply mounting to the root directory on each VM, but as I thought though the consequences I started to dream up more and more complicated way around the various control files created by each VM.
I became very obvious that trying to catch each possible conflict would be very time consuming and even then more than likely I'll not account for them all.
All my VM's are running ubuntu 23.10

QUESTION(S):
Is my assumption of update/upgrade the Master and reboot all a valid assumption

If all VM's are mounted to the respective root directories, is my conclusion that control files such as in /run directory will cause conflicts unless I modify the init.d/ scripts to create a file based on the machine name or similar

If rather than mounting the root directory, would it be safer and less work to mount the individual directories in the root directory that would allow the applications to be shared without file conflicts.
I was considering mounting: /etc /home /opt /snap /srv /usr and assigning a small disk space for the rest, although I think I'd create a shared /var/log director as well given that these files can grow very large.

Having gone a long way down the track of installing various application, I'm hoping to not throw it all out and start again in a more conventional NFS sharing data files and the applications with their respective control file remaining on small disks on each linked clone VM.

WHERE I've got to

I've so far created a single VM that contains most of the applications I want to run.
Apache2
NFS - server
NFS - client
Postfix
Mailcow
Cron
Docker
Icecast
Mopidy
Mysql
SSH
I haven't started testing the theories as I keep over thinking the potential problems and ways to prevent them from becoming problems